# Determining if string ends with another string

Tags: php

How do one determine,if the strings appears at the end of the other string. If they do then print true to standard out and false if they don’t. Would strpos will help?

```
    Sample Input

S1: “staff”
S2: “FF”
```

how would i make a function to run this,

```
  function matching_ends($s1,$s2){

}
```

Comment: One option would be using a decent language that has a [`.endswith()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) method on strings. ;)

Comment: PHP 8.0 introduces new methods for this job str_starts_with and str_end_with: http://stackoverflow.com/a/64160081/7082164

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php
$s1="testing";
$s2="ing";

echo matching_ends($s1, $s2);

function matching_ends($s1,$s2){
    return substr($s1, -strlen($s2)) == $s2 ? "true" : "false";
}
?>
```

**[Demo](http://codepad.org/zxYOaa8H)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
if( substr($s1, strlen($s1)-1) === substr($s2, strlen($s2)-1))
{
     // Do something when character at the last matches
}
else{
     // Do something when doesn't match
}
```

Comment: @Hanky Panky has a better answer. My code is only for matching the last character. I got the question wrong. :)

Comment: Then why not delete the post ;)

Comment: Also you could just do `-1` instead of using `strlen` there